# Windows Proxy Settings

Tags: windows, proxy

I work at a company where I need to access external websites through a proxy on Windows, and every time I do this I have to manually enter my LDAP credentials, which is making me quite irritated. I recently found a solution to configure the proxy in Linux Ubuntu WSL using environment variables in the **.bashrc** file, which made my life a lot easier. However, I'm having trouble finding a way to do something similar on Windows.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask your IT staff to streamline the process?

Comment: Have you considered that maybe this is what your IT staff intended? Perhaps they want you to enter your credentials each time so that they're not stored or cached? Have you asked them about it?

Comment: It seems that the business model of traditional "Stacks" platforms is becoming obsolete. It's a frustrating experience to say the least. The answers provided by "Artificial Intelligence" have been much more productive. The "Stack" as we know it will cease to exist very soon. Schumpeter predicted. Goodbye!